# iPhone unescaping string not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, string, parsing

In my app it accepts XML from the server. One of its functions returns a list of names, some having apostrophes (e.g. O'Reilly ).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
   <user id="123456" name="Pat O\'Reilly" is_qualified="false" />
```

In my parser I try two different methods to get rid of the escape slash, but neither of them work:

```
[[attributeDict valueForKey:@"name"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:@"'"]
```

and/or

```
[[attributeDict valueForKey:@"name"] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Printing these out both include the slash: Pat O\'Reilly. any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to replace is `@"\\\'"` with `@"\'"`

Both `\` and `'` are special characters.

You might even need to replace `@"\\\""` with `@"\""` for other texts that look like `blaname="bla is \"bla\" and bla"`.

Comment: hi @Dimme from your answer its seems like the server is unescaping the apostrophe incorrectly? The server should be retuning \\\' instead of \' ? sorry if I am misunderstanding this

Comment: Try this an you will understand: `NSLog(@"\\\'");` and `NSLog(@"\'");`

Comment: Ah, lightbulb moment. Thanks @Dimme :)